# Enable swipe-to-delete on UITableViewCell when UITableViewController inside UIPageViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using a `UITableViewController` inside a `UIPageViewController`.

My `UITableViewCell` has a swipe-to-delete, but when I swipe it, `UIPageViewController` grabs the gesture and moves to the next page.

Transition style is `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`, therefore a `gestureRecognizers` array is not allowed, as it would be in `UIPageViewController` header.

How do I get the swipe-to-delete gesture to work on the cell?

Comment: Do you want to disable swipe on `UITableViewCell` ?

Comment: @Bannings I want to enable swipe on cell first table section, for example. When I swipe on other table sections, UIPageViewController will move to the next page. But it is not possible, because UIPageViewController intercepts all swipes.

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable solution I've found so far is to in some manner handle the gestures yourself (e.g., install a scrollView, a pan gesture recognizer, a custom UIView subclass that handles touches, etc.).

I found another solution that is quick and actually works but is too hacky for my taste: https://github.com/WinterKirk/MKSlidingTableViewCell